# Using a private method as an action callback from within a class

Tags: functions, actions, private, callbacks

I have created a class from within which I would like to call a private method (from within the same class) from the `__construct` method as an action callback.

When I would like to use a public method I can access it by:

```
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'action_callback' ) );
```

However, this causes an error when the method is private. I have also tried unsuccessfully:

```
add_action('init', $this->action_callback() );
```

How do I access a private method?

The class looks something like:

```
class My_class {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'action_callback' ) );
    }

    private function action_callback() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: The best you could do is add `@access private` to the method doc, and also add an underscore before the method. Both of these will tell any experienced programmer that they should NOT be using the method, as it isn't intended to be public.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not possible to call a private method through an action or filter. When calling `add_action` or `add_filter`, WordPress adds the callback to a list of callbacks for that specific action or filter. Then, when `do_action` or `apply_filters` is called, WordPress uses `call_user_func_array` to call the linked functions and methods. As `call_user_func_array` is not called from within the class, it can't call private methods of that class.

Furthermore, there's no proper way to really keep the method private, even though you could add a separate (public) method to your class, add that as a callback to the action, and have that call the private method. In doing that, however, you lose the real concept of the method being private.