# Plugin Development using classes - Public & Private Callbacks

Tags: custom-post-types, php, plugin-development, hooks, oop

Alright, so I'm developing a plugin where my plugin file is a class which holds all the functions related to the initiation of the plugin, such that I can simply provide all of the plugins functionalities by initiating the class. According to a variety of docs, I developed stuff in a way where I hook all of the plugin's functionalities as callbacks onto the according hooks. Callbacks are defined as public functions in the class, and the callbacks are hooked via the class constructor; like so:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'MyPluginClass' ) ) {

  class MyPluginClass {

    public function __construct() {

      add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'my_admin_menus' );

    }

    public function my_admin_menus() {

      add_menu_page( ... );

    }

  }

}
```

okay, all of that worked. Now, when going over the plugin again; I felt weird looking at the final plugin and seeing about 50 public callbacks. That's why I attempted to privatize all of the plugin's main file callbacks, by changing for example the code above to:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'MyPluginClass' ) ) {

  class MyPluginClass {

    public function __construct() {

      add_action( 'admin_menu', function() { $this->my_admin_menus(); };

    }

    private function my_admin_menus() {

      add_menu_page( ... );

    }

  }

}
```

Okay, now don't get me wrong, my question's not about this transition, as there are many posts replying to this question; but rather how far this transition actually makes sense. I moreover faced several challenges, where one remained unexplained to me: when I change the callback which creates a custom post type with `register_post_type`from being `public` to being `private` (exactly as described above, so I won't paste the entire huge code here); the support columns disappear from the custom post type admin page (i.e. no more author, title, etc. columns, just a table having a row per created post, without column descriptions). Problems like these, and the several conundrums and workarounds I needed to code to make most of the callbacks `private` gave me the strong feeling that wordpress plugin development is not designed to use private callbacks. Am I wrong, or am I doing something wrong and it's indeed better (in terms of security) to privatize the main plugin callbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress hooks only work with global functions ( or public function inside a class ) - private or protected methods are not available due to their visibility level, so not available to the way WP calls actions or filters.

What you are trying to do is tidy up your code using a class to contain all the functions (
called methods inside a class ), this seems like a good idea, until you review it - and then you notice the bad code smell - you're writing proxy OOP - not real OOP - and this offers little justifiable benefit.

WordPress is partly responsible, but your plugin design is also responsible - you need to understand the patterns and refactor your plan - OR NOT.. because maybe it works better as procedural code than OOP...

Comment: well sorry for the title; true that it's not real OOP, so I changed that. Anyway, thanks for your answer but it doesn't really answer my point. I wonder if there's any benefit of privatizing all of the plugins' public callbacks or not.. (while I'll keep in mind that using classes this way to develop plugins may not be the best approach..)

Comment: The benefit of visibility of class methods is that you can have "functions" which are not part of the global scope of your application - that has multiple benefits, but only when working with objects and properties - as private global functions are not possible.

WordPress only works directly with public functions - that's not to say you can't use OOP, but you need to find a pattern that works, based on your application requirements.

Comment: This is a good topic on function and variable visibility: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361582/591486

Comment: Also - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/151830/7968

Comment: Last one - but good one - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/48094/7968

Comment: Yeh I know, but I actually use PHP namespaces and grouping of similar functions inside a class name to avoid touching the global scope anyways; and the pattern I provided above from switching from public to private works except for the custom post type registration; that's why I was wondering if what I'm doing actually makes sense from a wordpress point of view; and seemingly not, as wordpress calls hooked callbacks only when the hook is run, so outside of the function. Guess there's thus very little benefit of privatizing the functions here, and I should leave it as is..? Ur opinion?

Comment: and cheers; I'll check the links!

Comment: Okay the links explain the basics about visibility and using classes to hook callbacks in wordpress. As wordpress uses public callbacks with hooks, it is actually anyway not intended to use privatized or protected callbacks; that's how I understand it now. So I'll leave things as they are.. Do you see a security issue of leaving the callbacks in the main plugin file public; as in my code example? I mean generally end users shouldn't be able to access any of your PHP code anyway; so I guess that's safe enough?

Comment: My opinion is this - classes, visibility and encapsulation are powerful tools used correctly, and just because WordPress is not really OOP does not mean you can't write code that is - BUT.. at some point your app has to interact with WP, so do that in a way that is WP friendly - namely public function or some sort of factory pattern - and then use objects to deal with specific parts of your application flow.

Comment: Yupyup, alrighty, cheers mate, and a happy 21! :D

Comment: The issue is not "end-users" it is other plugins or themes - all public functions are public and if those functions give access to data which should not be public, that's an issue.. but, that said, there is no protection on access to the database, so most data in WP is public anyhow..